# Как создать переменную js из localstorage вывести на желтом фоне и потом удалить переменную с фоном на странице вывода после перезагрузки?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5

Как создать переменную js из localstorage вывести на желтом фоне и потом удалить переменную с фоном на странице вывода после перезагрузки?

```
document.querySelector(".demo").innerHTML =localstorage.getItem("a");
```

И вывожу через div id.  Надо чтобы если нету localstorage переменной поля и фона не было. Как задать это все, переменную, фон, и проверку есть ли переменная, и чтобы после перезагрузки страницы ее не было.

Comment: Что значит  "удалить переменную с фоном" ?

Comment: Чтобы фона желтого не было. А была пустая страница без текста.

Comment: Это фрагмент текста

Comment: Сейчас делаю через queryselector но не могу удалить фон после удаления переменной

Comment: Добавьте код (самодостаточный пример)

Comment: @Pavel добавил в описание.

Answer (score 0):

Если вы создаете Ваш див из JS примерно так:

```
const newDiv = document.createElement("div");
      newDiv.innerHTML = "<h1>Привет</h1>";
```

то

1. Вы должны удалить вашу переменную из localStorage: `localStorage.removeItem(key);`
2. Не обрисовывать этот `div` при маунте страницы

Если же это просто html вы можете удалить переменную из localStorage через document.querySelector выбрать этот див и удалить его `document.getElementById(myId).remove();`

Comment: Мне надо чтобы если она есть задавался стмль из css, а если нет то не задавался.

Comment: тогда вместо `remove` использовать `div.classList.remove("my-class");`, где div это ваш элемент `document.getElementById(myId)`

Comment: А можно пожалуйста еще раз момент с заданием стиля и созданием переменной и выводом на HTML если переменная существует и если не существует в локалсторидж?

Comment: Когда ваша переменная есть вы добавляете к div какой то class когда ее нет вы не добавляете class. А когда переменная удаляется в рантайме вы удаляете класс с этого дива

Comment: распишите пожалуйста(

Comment: Просто у меня есть в файле css, сили и я не знаю как их добавить. И все это выврдилось(